# Getting a part from a string

Tags: php, regex, string, explode

I am trying to collect all CatIDs from a site...the URL structure is...

> http://www.abc.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=12436777

I am interested in it `categoryId` which is in this case is `12436777`

My question is

Which is best, Regex or string explode??

if regex, please help me, I am very bad on it..

Also, I have to consider that URLs like

> http://www.abc.com/product/index.jsp?productId=12282785

I tried

```
$array = explode("http://www.abc.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=", $loc); 

foreach ($array as $part) {
        $zee[] = $part[1];
}
```

but it gives me nothing ..

thanks for help..

Comment: explode' s first param is the separator item. If you want to use it, do `$res=explode("=", $loc)` and the id will be in `$res[1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [parse_url](http://www.php.net/parse-url) to reliably give you the query string:

```
$parts = parse_url('http://www.abc.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=12436777');
```

and then [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse out the variables:

```
parse_str($parts['query'], $result);
echo $result['categoryId']; // outputs 12436777
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
http://.+?Id=(\d+)
```

The 1st group will contain the ID you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$url_parts = parse_url('http://www.abc.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=12436777');

if (isset($url_parts['query'])) {
  $query_parts = explode('&', $url_parts['query']); 

  $keys = array(); 
  foreach ($query_parts as $part) { 
      $item = explode('=', $part); 
      $keys[$item[0]] = $item[1]; 
  } 

  $category_id = isset($keys['categoryId']) ? $keys['categoryId'] : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Code:

```
$url = "http://www.abc.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=12436777";

$parts = Explode('=', $url);

$id = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
```

### Demonstration:

- http://stepolabs.com/lab/explode/index.php
- http://stepolabs.com/lab/explode/index.php.txt

Comment: For the end component of $parts just use end() function

Comment: Thanks for advice, I'll use it next time ^^.

Answer (score 1):

try...

```
  list(,$id) = explode('=','http://www.abc.com/product/index.jsp?productId=12282785');
```

this will work if there's **1** `=` in the string

Answer (score 1):

explode' s first param is the separator item. If you want to use it, try with something like:

```
$loc = "http://www.abc.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=12436777";
$res=explode("=", $loc);
```

and the id will be in `$res[1]`

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that what , is the only number, just do this

```
$st = "http://www.abc.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=12436777";

echo preg_filter('/[^0-9]/','',$st);
```