# Extracting Information from URL with PHP

Tags: php, url, url-parsing

I would like to use PHP to extract the information from a url. How can I get the value "matt" from the url:

```
www.shareit.me/matt
```

Also, how can I possibly check to see if there is a value there to begin with?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Use [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100249/getting-a-part-from-a-string/15100296#15100296

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to over-complicate things here:

```
$url  = 'www.shareit.me/matt';
$segs = explode('/', $url);
echo $segs[1]; // matt
```

Checking to see if it exists is as simple as `if ( !empty($segs[1]) ) {}`

Assuming you want the value `matt` and not just the "path", this will work with all these:

```
www.shareit.me/matt // matt
www.shareit.me/matt/photos
www.shareit.me/matt/photos/vacation/nebraska/cows/ // matt
www.shareit.me/matt/photos?vacation=mexico&gallery=donkeyshow // matt
www.shareit.me/matt/loves/cheese // matt
```

If you actually want people to know that matt loves cheese, you should use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) instead:

```
parse_url('www.shareit.me/matt/loves/cheese', PHP_URL_PATH); // /matt/loves/cheese
```

Answer (score 3):

voila, RTM:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
<?php

$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
print_r(parse_url($url));
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

Comment: This will give `/matt` not `matt`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [parse_url](http://php.net/parse-url) function, this will return an array with all the information about the URL. Something like this is probably what you would like:

```
echo explode('/', parse_url('http://www.shareit.me/matt')['path'])[1];
```

Comment: This will only work if the path only has a single parameter. What if the URL is `foo.com/matt/images`? I imagine he's trying to get a username or something from the URL.

Comment: @AlienWebguy changed my answer to allow multiple parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the url that is used to browse to the script, you use the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable.
In your case it will return this:

```
/matt
```

But you'll need to filter out the information you actual need.
For that you can use `preg_match` or an alternative way.
For more information about the `$_SERVER` variable: [see this page](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

If you want to get information of a string that contains a url, you can use

> explode("/", $url);

Answer (score 1):

### Code:

```
$url = "http://www.shareit.me/matt";

$parts = Explode('/', $url);

$id = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
```

### Demonstration:

- http://stepolabs.com/lab/explode/index.php
- http://stepolabs.com/lab/explode/index.php.txt

*By the way [Getting a part from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100249/getting-a-part-from-a-string/15100296#15100296)*.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex with `preg_match`

```
preg_match("/.\/(.*)$/",$url,$matches);
```

than check matches if it contains what you want

Comment: -1, that would add unnecessary overhead, plus you have a native function to do exactly that: [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url)

Comment: yes I wasn't aware of this function, still I cannot understand the downvote, thanks for leaving a comment :)